# Positioning of Figures in latex

Tags: graphics, positioning

How can I place figures like this:

[image: Figures positioning]

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Do you mean to place "images" like shown, or "figures"?  The term "figure" in LaTeX implies captioning, and so to placing "figures" as shown would imply you want a caption under each box.

Comment: Do  you search in SE for similar questions? Here is a many similar questions ... For star try to enclose your images in `minipages`, for example If they actually are sub-images in one figure.

Comment: Thanks Steven, Yes I want to place images like shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I show many of the same "image", given as `\img`.  To make them different, replace each instance of `\img` with a some code that generates the desired image, as I have shown in 3 cases.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel,xcolor,graphicx} 
\def\img{\textcolor{blue!100!green!50}{\rule{2.5cm}{2cm}}}
\newlength\gap
\gap=2ex\relax
\newcommand\hgap[1][1]{\hspace{#1\gap}}
\def\imgA{\includegraphics[width=2.5cm,height=2cm]{example-image-A}}
\def\imgB{\includegraphics[width=2.5cm,height=2cm]{example-image-B}}
\def\imgC{\includegraphics[width=2.5cm,height=2cm]{example-image-C}}
\begin{document}
\stackon[2\gap]{\imgA\hgap\img\hgap\scalerel*{\stackon[.5\gap]{\imgC}{\img}}{\img}}%
  {\img\hgap[.5]\imgB}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Steven, Can you please tell me how to insert caption below each image

Comment: @Benish stacking figures and captions is a completely separate issue, which is why I asked it originally to your question.  But again, it depends on what you mean by captions.  For example, this approach will not work if you want the captions to be of the form "Figure 1", "Figure  2"... where those figure numbers are part of the figure count (show up in list of figures, and/or can be referred to with `\label` and `\ref`).  For that, a `minipage` approach would be best.  If the "captions" are of the form (a) (b)..., then look into the `subcaption` package. (continuing)

Comment: @Benish The `subcaption` package will allow subfigure labels that can be referred to with `\label` and `\ref` style referencing.  If, however, the third possibility is that you want words under each image, but they aren't required to show up in the list of figures, or be individually referenced by subfigure, **then** the current approach can work.  In that case, you can `\def\imgA{\stackunder{\includegraphics[...]{...}}{sub-words}}`